# Get a list of all classes loaded in the jvm for a lambda function

Tags: java, aws-lambda, jvm

I'm trying to find a method to see the number of classes loaded by the JVM for a lambda function.
I have a sample code from a friend but it does not work.
I have the following:

```
java -cp my.jar -verbose:class Handler | grep Loaded
```

It must be missing something because I don't have the "Loaded" classes.
Is "load" the replacement of "Loaded" ?

The result of this is something like:

```
[0.179s][info][class,load] java.text.Format source: jrt:/java.base
[0.179s][info][class,load] java.text.MessageFormat source: jrt:/java.base
[0.179s][info][class,load] java.util.Locale$Category source: jrt:/java.base
[0.179s][info][class,load] java.util.Locale$1 source: jrt:/java.base
[0.180s][info][class,load] java.text.FieldPosition source: jrt:/java.base
[0.180s][info][class,load] java.util.Date source: jrt:/java.base
```

I was expecting something like:

```
[Opened /usr/java/j2sdk1.4.1/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Opened /usr/java/j2sdk1.4.1/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar]
[Opened /usr/java/j2sdk1.4.1/jre/lib/jsse.jar]
[Opened /usr/java/j2sdk1.4.1/jre/lib/jce.jar]
[Opened /usr/java/j2sdk1.4.1/jre/lib/charsets.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Object from /usr/java/j2sdk1.4.1/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.io.Serializable from /usr/java/j2sdk1.4.1/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Comparable from /usr/java/j2sdk1.4.1/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.CharSequence from /usr/java/j2sdk1.4.1/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.String from /usr/java/j2sdk1.4.1/jre/lib/rt.jar]
```

Do you know what I'm missing ? Why I don't see the "loaded" classes ?
I have `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS`

Thanks.
C.C.

Comment: Looks like `-verbose` prints to standard error stream.

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand what this really means. Can you expand ?

Comment: It is long story. Try `java -cp my.jar -verbose:class Handler &2>1 | grep Loaded`

Comment: Tried, same result

Comment: JDK 9 introduced [Unified JVM Logging](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/158). In particular, it modifies the format of GC, Class Loading and other JVM logs. See the [linked JEP](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/158) for details. `[class,load]` lines replace older `[Loaded XYZ]` messages.

Comment: Thanks. I tried with java 8 and java 11 and I saw the difference

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer.
The expected results is on Java 8.
In Java 11 the result is not the same, so I have to adapt my command for each version.

Answer (score 0):

The class count would be possible to get in the actual program using

```java
Field jvmField = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getClass().getDeclaredField("jvm");
jvmField.setAccessible(true);
VMManagement jvmInstance = (VMManagement) jvmField.get(ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean());

int totalClassCount = jvmInstance.getTotalClassCount();
int loadedClassCount = jvmInstance.getLoadedClassCount();
```

Tested in java 8

Answer (score -1):

Please try with below Classes .Hope this works for you

```
java -cp my.jar -verbose:class Handler | grep 'Load*\|Open*'
java -cp my.jar -verbose:class Instrumentation | grep 'Load*\|Open*'
java -cp my.jar -verbose:class Serialisation | grep 'Load*\|Open*'
```